# Why does Frankie welcome The Saint and Emma as familiar persons?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-saint

In [The Saint](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120053) (1997), Frankie says to The Saint Emma something like

> I know you both and also I am waiting for you. Will you buy my art?

Actually, The Saint and Emma are complete strangers to Frankie and vice versa. Then why is she welcoming them as if they are familiar to her?

Answer (score 1):

> *Frankie*: where have you been? I've been waiting for two hours. Come on! I've got some beautiful things for you to buy.

**TL;DR**: Frankie welcomes them as customers for her business. She's offering a way out for money.

From "The chase scene - "The Saint" - 1997

Frankie is a [spiv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiv). It means that she knows all one has to know about the "*business*" (read "*illegal*") one can make. She knew Simon and Emma were chased by Tretiak's son Ilya and his mobs, so it's a good opportunity for her to make some money (later, she'll even trade Simon's Bulgari watch for a way out of the catacombs). That's why she was looking for them.

Beside that, when you're a spiv, you hear pretty much everything quickly from the street. And Simon and Emma aren't precisely the stereotype of a loving couple hanging around the streets of Moscow on a honeymoon. It seems obvious that Frankie and her mates were willing to step outside the bounds of the Tretiak family for their own benefit.

The best way is to find them first, wait for them, and offer her help. Customer service.